# Terraform data block for azurerm_resource_group not working, If we add resources

Tags: azure, terraform, devops

RG Creation process:

root module:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
    count    = var.lookup == true ? 0 : 1
    name     = var.resource_group_name
    location = var.location
    tags     = var.tags
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "resource_group" {
  count      = var.lookup == true ? 1 : 0
  name       = var.resource_group_name
  depends_on = [var.resource_group_name]
}
```

caller side:

```
module "resource_group" {
  source              = "../../modules/resource_group"
  count               = length(var.resource_groups)
  resource_group_name = var.resource_groups[count.index].name
  location            = var.resource_groups[count.index].location
  is_default          = try(var.resource_groups[count.index].is_default, false)
}
```

input:

```
    {"resource_groups": [
        {
            "name": "rg1",
            "location": "westus2"
        }
    ]}
```

I am using data block inside aks main module like below

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "main" {
  name = var.resource_group_name
}

module "ssh-key" {
  source         = "./modules/ssh-key"
  public_ssh_key = var.public_ssh_key == "" ? "" : var.public_ssh_key
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "main" {
  name                    = var.cluster_name == null ? "${var.prefix}-aks" : var.cluster_name
  kubernetes_version      = var.kubernetes_version
  location                = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
  resource_group_name     = "${data.azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  dns_prefix              = var.prefix
  sku_tier                = var.sku_tier
```

caller side AKS looks like this:

```
module "aks" {
  count                            = length(var.aks)
  source                           = "../../modules/aks"
  resource_group_name              = var.aks[count.index].resource_group_name
  kubernetes_version               = try(var.aks[count.index].kubernetes_version, "1.21.1")
  orchestrator_version             = try(var.aks[count.index].orchestrator_version, "1.21.1")
  prefix                           = join("", [local.prefix, "aks", var.aks[count.index].id])
  cluster_name                     = join("", [local.prefix, "aks", var.aks[count.index].id])
```

I am passing inputs to above module Lets say var.resource_group_name = rg1, it will work without any issue. However if I add new rg to create. Data block not working as expected, aks cluster force to re create, I confirmed its problem with data block the way I am using. Because I changed hard coded values in aks for rg name and location instead of data block and it is working.

Example of adding new rg2 input looks like this

```
        {"resource_groups": [
            {
                "name": "rg1",
                "location": "westus2"
            },
            {
                "name": "rg2",
                "location": "westus2"
            }

        ]}
```

Comment: What does it mean not working? Any errors?

Comment: AKS cluster re create, If I add new resource group creation. rg data block not querying right resource group name and location

Comment: @Vidya, can you please tell if there is any caller side for aks module as well ? if there can you add that to the question as well

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT, Added as you suggested